# My c++ code for factoring isn't working

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to create a c++ program that when I input two numbers (num1, combinationNum), it finds two numbers that multiply together to equal num1, but add together to equal combinationNum. It currently works for positive integers, but not negative. How do I make it work with negative integers? Also, If the equation isn't solvable, I would like it to print an error of some sort. Thanks! 
Code:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Factor
//
//  Created by Dani Smith on 2/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dani Smith Productions. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;



void factors(int num, int comNum){
int a, b;
cout<<"The factors are ";
bool isPrime = true;
int root = (int)sqrt((double)num);

for(int i = 2; i <= root; i++){
    if(num % i == 0 ){
        isPrime = false;
        //cout<<i<<",";

        for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){
            if(x==1){
                a = i;
            }
            else if(x == 2){
                b = i;
            }
            if(a + b == comNum){
                cout << a << ", and " << b << ".";
            }

        }

    }

}
        //----------------------------------------
if(isPrime)cout<<"1 "; 
cout<<endl; 
}

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, multiple = 0, combinationNum = 0, output1 = 0, output2 = 0;
cout << "What number do you want to factor?\n";
cin >> num1;
cout << "What do you want them to add to?\n";
cin >> combinationNum;
factors(num1, combinationNum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it was working before, why not put it back to the state in which it was working? What exactly about this indicates that it "isn't working?" What input do you give when the output is incorrect?

Comment: `It was working before, but I messed around with it too much` -- this is why programmers use source control.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem exactly? And if it worked before then you know how to make it work, so simply go ahead and do that. We are not a "damn I lost my code I'll get the internet to recreate it for me because I can't be bothered to suffer for my mistakes" service!

Comment: are you aware of delta and squared equation? you have two equations and two variables, why don't you use delta and formulas for roots of polynomial?

Comment: Start from scratch; you do not need 100 lines of code to solve a straightforward quadratic equation.

Comment: I messed around with it because I was trying to make it work with negative numbers.

Comment: Not enough. You say it "doesn't work for negative integers". In what way does it "not work"? What debugging have you performed?

Comment: With `x + y == a` and `x * y == b`, you have to solve `y == a - x`
and `x * x - a * x + b == 0`... `delta == a * a - 4 * b` and `x12 = (a +- sqrt(delta)) / 2`...

Comment: When I say it does't work, I mean it don't output anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve:

```
x + y == a
x * y == b
```

You have to solve

```
y == a - x
x * x - a * x + b == 0
```

So with `delta == a * a - 4 * b`, if `delta` positive, the solutions are

```
x1 = (a + sqrt(delta)) / 2
x2 = (a + sqrt(delta)) / 2
```

The code : (https://ideone.com/qwrSwa)

```
void solve(int sum, int mul)
{
    std::cout << "solution for x + y = " << sum << std::endl
              << "             x * y = " << mul << std::endl;
    const int delta = sum * sum - 4 * mul;
    if (delta < 0) {
        std::cout << "No solution" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    const float sqrtdelta = sqrtf(delta);
    const float x1 = (sum + sqrtdelta) / 2.f;
    const float x2 = (sum - sqrtdelta) / 2.f;

    std::cout << "x = " << x1 << ", y = " << sum - x1 << std::endl;
    if (delta != 0) {
        std::cout << "x = " << x2 << ", y = " << sum - x2 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to solve: x + y == a, and x * y == a for x and y

Comment: Could you please explain how it works or add comments? Thanks!

Comment: @DaniM.Smith: `x + y == sum` <=> `y == sum - x`, if you substitute `y` in the second equation, you will have `x * x - sum * x + mul == 0` which is a [Quadratic_equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation). This equation has known solutions. once `x` is known, `y` can be resolved easily (`y == sum - x`).